# Which maven archetype code should be selected for Jackrabbit First Hops example?

Tags: java, maven, jackrabbit

I am new to Maven and Jackrabbit and I am starting with FirstHops example given on Apache site but I am not sure which archetype code should be selected for creating this project in maven. My default code shows 511.

I have already tried with 511 code. After creating project with this I changed the dependencies in pom.xml as provided with FirstHops example.

When I tried to compile,no error but when I tried to package it gave me a long list of errors.

```
[ERROR] /S:/mvnapp/FirstHop2/src/test/java/org/shobhan/jr/AppTest.java:[5,23] S:
\mvnapp\FirstHop2\src\test\java\org\shobhan\jr\AppTest.java:5: package junit.fra
mework does not exist
[ERROR] /S:/mvnapp/FirstHop2/src/test/java/org/shobhan/jr/AppTest.java:[11,13] S
:\mvnapp\FirstHop2\src\test\java\org\shobhan\jr\AppTest.java:11: cannot find sym
bol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to provide an answer without your pom file and the AppTest.java, but it seems like you are doing junit tests in AppTest.java and junit is missing in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks I removed AppTest.java file from test folder, packaged worked now.